# How to get the modified date and time for item versions in Sitecore via Graphql query

Tags: graphql

I need the query to get  date modified on item versions for an item.

[https://scnew9.3cm.dev.local//sitecore/api/graph/items/master/ui?sc_apikey={api-key}&query=query%0A%7B%0A%20%20item(path%3A%20%22%2Fsitecore%2Fcontent%2Fhome%22)%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20versions%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D](https://scnew9.3cm.dev.local//sitecore/api/graph/items/master/ui?sc_apikey=%7Bapi-key%7D&query=query%0A%7B%0A%20%20item(path%3A%20%22%2Fsitecore%2Fcontent%2Fhome%22)%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20versions%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

[image]

Need the Date Modified for the item versions
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the field `__updated` which will hold the value of the updated date of the item. Below is how your GraphQL will look like:

```
{
  item(path: "/sitecore/Content/Home", language: "en") {
    name
    versions {
      path
      field(name: "__updated"){
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**The result:**

[image]

Note that if you want to add the name of the user who modified the item, you should use the name `__updated by`. Below is a snippet when using the `__updated by`

```
{
  item(path: "/sitecore/Content/Home", language: "en") {
    name
    versions {
      path
      updatedby: field(name: "__updated by") {
        value
      }
      updatedDate: field(name: "__updated"){
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Outcome:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Hishaam Namooya